# output is not what I want

Tags: matlab

My problem is:

I have a matrix `2888x16` and I want to calculate some conditions with it

I want the result in a new matrix that follow the next conditions:

- values below 3, my output has to be equals 0(zero)
- values above 13, my output has to be 2050,
- and last condition, values between 3 and 13 follow a complicated
  equation showed in the code.

The problem is:
when I run the code only the last `'else'` is computed. The first `'if'` and `'elseif'` isn't computed.

Here is my code:

```
    for i = 1:iw;
    ii=1:16;

    if w_speed80_win(i,ii) < 3;
        eout_win(i,ii) = 0;
    elseif w_speed80_win(i,ii) >= 13;
        eout_win(i,ii) = 2050;
    else
        eout_win(i,ii) = (0.13966*(w_speed80_win(i,ii).^5))-(6.1113*(w_speed80_win(i,ii).^4))...
            +(97.045*(w_speed80_win(i,ii).^3))-(676.62*(w_speed80_win(i,ii).^2))+(2193.5*w_speed80_win(i,ii))-2632.2;
    end
end
```

Comment: code seems all-right may be the data is meeting only else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be simpler to keep it vectorized:

```
eout_win = (0.13966*(w_speed80_win.^5))-(6.1113*(w_speed80_win.^4))...
            +(97.045*(w_speed80_win.^3))-(676.62*(w_speed80_win.^2))+(2193.5*w_speed80_win)-2632.2;
eout_win(w_speed80_win<3)=0
eout_win(w_speed80_win>=13)=2050
```

You can also check that `w_speed80_win` indeed contains values less than 3 with:

```
i, ii = find(w_speed80_win<3)
```

which will give you the indices of values that are lower than 3.

Comment: You're right!
I'm a 'noob' and the worst thing i could do is complicate my codes.
Your solution is much more simpler and works better..
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ind_LT_3 = w_speed80_win < 3 ;
ind_GT_13 = w_speed80_win > 13 ;
ind_REST = ~(ind_LT_3 | ind_GT_13 ) ;
w_speed80_win(ind_LT_3 ) = 0;
w_speed80_win(ind_GT_13 ) = 2050;
w_speed80_win(ind_REST ) = (0.13966*(w_speed80_win.^5)) - ..
```

Comment: well.. that was an improvement in my code. Thanks a lot for that.
Unfortunately now appears another error. 
That's my new code as you suggested.

ind_LT_3 = w_speed80_win < 3 ;

ind_GT_13 = w_speed80_win > 13 ;
ind_REST = ~(ind_LT_3 | ind_GT_13 ) ;

eout_win(ind_LT_3) = 0;
eout_win(ind_GT_13) = 2050;

eout_win(ind_REST) = (0.13966*(w_speed80_win.^5))...

In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in file_era_interim (line 65)
eout_win(ind_REST) = (0.13966*...

And my eout_win, with first two conditions has the size of 1x46208 instead of 2888x16.

Comment: I've found my error yet! The code works fine now!
Thanks a lot! :D